# Upgrade MySqlConnector .Net version 6.3.7+ crashes Mono 2.10.2 with: The assembly name is invalid

Tags: .net, mono, mysql-connector

I have an ASP.Net site working well with MySql Connector.Net (MySql.Data.dll version 6.3.6).  However, because of a bug in the version I need to move to 6.3.7 (or 6.4.4).

However, when I install the new DLL, mono is crashing with:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: The assembly name is invalid.
  at System.Reflection.AssemblyName..ctor (System.String assemblyName) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.CSharp.ImportedAssemblyDefinition.ReadAttributes () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.CSharp.MetadataImporter.GetAssemblyDefinition (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.CSharp.ReflectionImporter.ImportAssembly (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace targetNamespace) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.CSharp.DynamicLoader.LoadReferences (Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer module) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in :0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0
```

The compile line looks fine:

```
gmcs /target:library /lib:"/www/services0/bin" /debug+ /optimize- /warn:4 /out:"tmp/apache-temp-aspnet-0/2049672d/App_global.asax_20af2b38.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Data/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Services/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.Services.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Runtime.Serialization/3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.IdentityModel/3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.IdentityModel.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel/3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.ServiceModel.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.ServiceModel.Web/3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.Extensions/3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.Extensions.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml.Linq/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll" /r:"/usr/local/lib/mono/gac/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Common.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Eagle.Catapult.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Eagle.Connection.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Enyim.Caching.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Infragistics35.Web.v10.1.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Infragistics35.WebUI.Shared.v10.1.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebChart.v10.1.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Membase.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Metadata.Utility.XmlSerializers.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Metadata.Utility.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/MySql.Data.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/Services.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/StmEncoderLibrary.dll" /r:"/www/services0/bin/log4net.dll"  /nowarn:0169 /d:DEBUG  -- "tmp/apache-temp-aspnet-0/2049672d/App_global.asax_20af2b38_0.cs"
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Aha...it seems if you use the version 2 connector .dll it fails.  Version 4 connector works. Not sure why it matters.